# How to unpersist the cache’d data frame which is created on top of another data frame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to unpersist the cache’d data frame which was created on top of another data frame

I have created multiple data frame from the parent df, at the end of the code I’m creating a final df after all the transformations are completed, which will contain around 100 billions of records and the previous df also will deal with the same volume of data. So i have decided to release all the df’s once my final df is created which ready to write in to parquet file.

Can someone help me how to release the unused df’s before saving the final df in to parquet files in hdfs, I hope this will free the space in memory and helps in writing the final df in to parquet file faster

Comment: could you specify which dataframe you want to unpersist? what do you mean by releasing the `unused` dfs? which dfs are unused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cached a dataframe using `df.cache()`, you can do `df.unpersist()` to remove that dataframe from memory. If you have overwritten the variable `df`, then you can't unpersist it because the reference is lost.

There is still a final way of clearing everything from the cache, which is `spark.catalog.clearCache()`, but that's probably not what you want, because you want to keep the final result dataframe.

It is important not to overwrite any variables which correspond to cached dataframes, so that you keep the reference to that dataframe.

Comment: I will try this option, also I'm not overwriting the result to existing df, every time  when I'm creating a new df it is created with new name only, so I hope it will not get impacted when I'm un persisting the unused df's. 
one more doubt will the unpersist work if i persisted using ```df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)?

Comment: @Haridev yes, it works for any storage levels.